# Stereo image 3d reconstruction

Tags: image-processing, 3d

I am looking for 3D reconstruction software that can extract 3D model (depth map) from 2 images (It would be great if it work for structured light pairs). I am looking for best accuracy (bulding ground truth). I do not care at all about performance (even if it takes a day to reconstruct one stereo pair accurately).

Note: both free and commercial software are acceptable. Windows/Linux/Mac are acceptable.

Comment: Hello Humam, did you ever find a solution to your question?